# Compare two Counter object in python with ==

Tags: python

I have two string and I will like to compare is the number of character matched each other. The away I think of is to use collections.Counter to build a Counter object with character as key and display frequency as value and then use `==` to compare if it is matched. But my question leads to if it is valid to use `==` to compare two Counter objects? does that compare each keys and value all identical?

ex:

```
string_one = 'aaaaab'
string_two = 'aabaaa'
Counter(string_one) == Counter(string_two) # should be True

string_one = 'aaaaab'
string_two = 'aabaac'
Counter(string_one) == Counter(string_two) # should be False
```

Comment: Sure, it's syntactically correct. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Those **are** true and false. Only your comment character of `//` is wrong; should be `#` in Python

Comment: Why ask something so trivial that you can try in 15 seconds flat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**

per: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

> Counters support rich comparison operators for equality, subset, and
> superset relationships: ==, !=, <, <=, >, >=. All of those tests treat
> missing elements as having zero counts so that Counter(a=1) ==
> Counter(a=1, b=0) returns true.

New in 3.10:

> Changed in version 3.10: In equality tests, missing elements are
> treated as having zero counts. Formerly, Counter(a=3) and Counter(a=3,
> b=0) were considered distinct.

Comment: I added an important proviso to the quote you have there...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, two `Counter`s compare equal if and only if they have the same keys, and each key maps to the same value. The docs don't say that straight out, but it's implied by its saying "a `Counter` is a `dict` subclass". From that you can deduce that a `Counter` acts like a `dict` unless otherwise specified. Then, from the `dict` docs:

> Dictionaries compare equal if and only if they have the same (key, value) pairs (regardless of ordering). Order comparisons (‘<’, ‘<=’, ‘>=’, ‘>’) raise TypeError.
> Blockquote

Although, as @JonSG's answer partly says, some changes were made to this starting in version 3.10. For example,

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> a = Counter()
>>> b = Counter()
>>> a[3] = 0
>>> a
Counter({3: 0})
>>> b[9837] = 0
>>> b
Counter({9837: 0})
>>> a == b # starting in 3.10 missing acts like they map to 0 in `==`
True
>>>
```

Whether that's an improvement I leave to your judgment ;-)

Comment: However, there is a surprise perhaps of `Counter(a=1) == Counter(a=1, b=0)` is `True` so your statement *two Counters compare equal if and only if they have the same keys* is not true.

Comment: Yes, I added new text apparently while you were commenting. Do note that what you said is true now, but wasn't true before the 3.10 release.

Comment: I actually agree with you: It is a head-scratcher addition.

Comment: With `a=Counter(a=1)` and `ab=Counter(a=1, b=0)` you have the additional perverse result of `a==ab` is `True` but `dict(a)==dict(ab)` is `False`.

Comment: We're straying from what's sensible in comments, but I'll just add I believe this was done to make the new-in-3.10 "is a subset?" interpretation of `<` and friends reasonable in endcases. As a multiset, the empty `Counter` is a subset of every multiset, so `Counter() <= C` needed to be true for every `C` having non-negative values. And for multisets, it's desirable too that `C == D` if and only if `C <= D` and `D <= C`. In your example, viewed as multisets, `a` and `ab` certainly are each a subset of the other.

Comment: I guess I vote for `a<ab` being `True` -- it is not, it is False since it cannot be both equal to and less than...

Comment: As multisets, for `a<ab` to be `True`, it must be the case that `ab` has an element that `a` does not have. But they both contain one instance of "a", and no instances of anything else. There is no "proper" subset relation between them.